# $f(x,y)=\frac{x\sin (y)}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $f(0,0)=0$. Is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Determine if the function is differentiable:
$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if }(x,y)\ne (0,0)\\
0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$.

So I started by calculating the partial derivatives at the point $(0,0)$ and for both my result was $0$.

After that, I plugged them in the limit and got

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h\sin(k)}{(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}}$.

and from that point I'm lost because I don't know what I should do next to determine anything by that, and I'm not even sure if I'm going in the right direction with this.

Comment: yes yes im editing it

Comment: Observe that your function is essentially homogeneous, $\sin y\approx y$ when $y\approx 0$, so it does not have a limit at $(0,0)$. Try to prove that.

Comment: youre right thats the better approach

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the path $y=x$:
$$f(x,x)=\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+x^2}\sim \frac{x^2}{2x^2}\to \frac{1}{2} $$
Now consider a second path $y=0$:
$$f(x,0)=\frac{x\sin 0}{x^2}=0\to 0 $$
The function is not continuous and hence can't be differentiable.